# Free screen capture software for recording Minecraft videos

Tags: windows, gratis, screen-recording

I am looking for screen capture software to record Minecraft videos for YouTube.

I need a software that fulfills the following criteria:

1. Is lightweight and won't slow down my game
2. Free
3. Works with Windows 10
4. Records audio from a headset and from desktop
5. No watermark

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com/)
From their website:

> - High performance real time video/audio capturing and mixing, with unlimited scenes you can switch between seamlessly via custom
>     transitions.
> - Intuitive audio mixer with per-source filters such as noise gate, noise suppression, and gain. Take full control with VST plugin
>     support.
> - Filters for video sources such as image masking, color correction, chroma/color keying, and more.
> - Powerful and easy to use configuration options. Add new Sources, duplicate existing ones, and adjust their properties effortlessly.
> - Streamlined Settings panel for quickly configuring your broadcasts and recordings. Switch between different profiles with ease.
> - Light and dark themes available to fit your environment.

Answer (score 2):

The best lightweight screen capturing software is [**Camstudio**](http://camstudio.org) as it is only 11 Mb.

- Record from your screen
- Open source
- Add annotations / audio supported
- Save video in any video format (quality is adjustable/frame rates)
- Screen capturing modes (fullscreen, part)

Also check the [**OBS Studio**](https://obsproject.com) and [**FlashBack Express**](https://www.flashbackrecorder.com/express/).
These two softwares got more features than the lightweight Camstudio. You would be able to do a professional job.

- Audio mixer
- Streamlined settings panel for quickly configuring your broadcasts
- Various plugins
- Customizable profiles with customized settings
- Sub region (the screen capturing area is customizable)

But there is this thing that you should note:

- Scene transitions are hard cut. It is not much nice.